# Правильное составление URL

Tags: url

Появился такой вопрос: Как правильно составить URL страницы, что бы поисковики его нормально индексировали и подсвечивали нужные слова (город)?
Составить надо из двух городов и их кодов, например:

1. Москва - MOW
2. Самара - KUF

Я остановился на таком варианте:
domainname.ru/Москва(MOW)_Самара(KUF).html

Но не уверен что это лучший вариант т.к. использую скобки. Может лучше использовать двоеточие или вертикальную черту для разделения названия города и его кода? Нижнее подчеркивание используется как разделитель между городами, а дефис присутствует в названиях многих городов и использовать его еще раз в адресе не хочется (разбирать адрес будет сложнее).

Подскажите, как еще можно все это скомпоновать.

Comment: За скобки или вертикальную черту в URL нужно бить. Это ещё допускается в области параметров (после знака вопроса ?).

За двоеточие бить очень сильно))

Да и русские буквы не слишком желательны.

Но, чтоб поисковики что-то подсвечивали этого мало будет

Comment: @grisha не страдайте маразмом, используйте общепринятые стандарты!

Comment: Спасибо за коменты, но не могли бы вы посказать что с этим можно сделать? Как мне это все впихнуть в URL...да чтоб корректно было. Русские быквы в УРЛ на сайте уже давно и если все переделывать под транслит, то под переиндекс попалут более 10к страниц.

Пока ни скобки и ничего другого кроме тире и почеркиваний не использовал, но теперь надо отделить КОД-города от его названия (тире и подчеркивание уже заняты...нажо както по другому)...как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и используйте подчёркивание.
А в коде разбивайте строку по подчёркиванию, выйдет 4 части:
город1, код-города1, город2, код-города2
Никаких сложностей.